# Op-amp square wave to triangle wave converter not working as expected

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, ltspice, waveform, integrator

A follow-up to [a similar question from yesterday](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/613669/square-wave-to-triangle-wave-converter-using-op-amp-not-working) since the problem I've run into has differed enough to warrant something more than an edit.

I have built an integrator to act as a 5V 32Hz square wave to triangle wave converter.

[image]

This is my output.

[image]

We can see that the voltage is offset too high, which is strange because per my understanding of integrators, the voltage offset should be equal to the "ground" voltage, which is 2.5V.

One way of changing this behavior is modifying the high value feedback resistor. This is an example of the resistor (R2) with a reduced resistance (200k). The closer the feedback resistor is to 0, the lower the offset.

[image]

I am unsure why this has such an effect on the offset voltage. Since reducing the high value feedback resistor results in a more rounded triangle wave and I don't want that (I am using the triangle for modulation on a CD4046 VCO chip,) I'm trying to figure out a way to reduce the offset voltage without distorting the triangle wave.

The [LTspice model](https://www.mediafire.com/file/tgfih0nnv9d60fw/PWM+to+Triangle+Wave.asc/file) if anyone needs it. If more info is needed for this issue, please let me know.

Edit: A close-up of the square wave.

[image]

Comment: Previously, I asked you to wait 20 seconds for the output to settle down - have you done that?

Comment: I did wait 20 seconds. the results were not changed.

Comment: Is that a square wave input with equal mark to space or a rectangular wave?

Comment: If your square input is not "perfect" (duty cycle = 0.5 ...), you need another integrator for a feedback correction to the first integrator offset ... Without this, it will always drift ... and finally "saturate" high or low.

Comment: An input waveform with a non 50% duty cycle will cause the integrator's output to go to an offset where the duty cycle is balanced by the discharge effect that the feedback resistor has on the capacitor.

Comment: My square input is likely to be not perfect. How would I go about adding this other integrator?

Comment: @HFOrangefish hold on mister orangefish; how do you estimate that your input signal is `likely to be not perfect` - from what I can tell of the numbers in the sim circuit it's perfect. Maybe replace it with a 2.5 volt DC source and check that the op-amp output remains close to 2.5 volts. If this doesn't happen then there's something possibly wrong with your AD822 model. However, I'm unsure what the "1000" is for at the end of the pulse definition line (my sim doesn't have that).

Comment: By not perfect, I mean that the rise and fall time influences the duty cycle. In LTSpice, the 1000 is the number of cycles that the square wave generator generates.
And I'm planning to build this circuit for real, with a MCU's PWM acting as the square wave anyways. I have tested the circuit with a 2.5 DC source and the op-amp output remains close to 2.5 Volts.

Comment: Then you have an imprecise square wave. I urge you to look into this and correct it. Maybe use cycle times of 0.032 seconds and on period of 0.016 seconds to rule out any fractional anomalies. Set rise and fall to zero. You could also reinstall the voltage pulse source but set both upper and lower amplitudes to be 2.5 volts and see what happens. If that looks OK set upper voltage to be 3 volts and lower voltage to be 2 volts. Step and repeat and observe.

Comment: A CD4047 IC has an RC oscillator driving a digital divide-by-two that produces an absolute perfect squarewave with even high and low times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On an LTSpice simulation, I was able to improve the output waveform (V_triangle) by specifying Tr (rise time) and Tf (fall time) as 1n, rather than 0.

I checked the mark-space ratio of V_square with 0 for Tr and Tf: the waveform was visibly skewed to longer at 0 V than 5 V. When I changed Tr and Tf to 1n, the input waveform (V_square) changed to 50-50 mark-space. The output voltage then settled as a triangle centered on 2.5 V.

EDIT

Here is my result, starting at around 4 sec. (Note that the time constant of R2*C1 is 1 sec.)
[image]

Comment: You don't need to impose tighter `tr/tf` iff all you want is to see a triangle. It's enough to make `Ton` such that the resulting `Ton+tr=T/2`. Since `tr=min(Ton,T-Ton)/10`, you can solve this with `x+x/10=1/2`, resulting in `Ton={5/11}`. Sure enough, [it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUSsP.png), albeit with smooth corners (due to the `time**2/2` integration of the ramps).

Answer (score 3):

A couple of points on LTspice:
If you want continuous pulses you don't need to set the number of cycles, you can leave that blank and it will just keep going.
You should set the rise and fall times, otherwise LTspice does it for you, and they probably won't be what you want. If you want them to be nearly vertical, use a very small value, 1n, 1u, or even 1p in some cases.

```
PULSE(5 0 0 1n 1n 0.015625 0.03125)
```

If you know the real rise and fall times that you are expecting from your circuit use those instead, the better the data going in, the better the results coming out.

You can improve the accuracy of the simulation by changing a number of settings and options, the most common way is to add these commands

```
.OPTIONS plotwinsize=0
.OPTIONS numdgt=7
```

If you don't specify a timestep in your transient simulation command LTspice will come up with it's own, which again will probably not be what you want. You can also delay the start of recording data to let the circuit stabilize. This statement waits 3.5 seconds, and then plots the next 0.5 seconds, with a timestep of 100uS. This will give better resolution but run slower.

```
.tran 0 4 3.5 100u
```

Try these techniques and see if they don't improve your simulations.

Comment: Specifying `tr/tf` to be that ridiculously low is an unneded exaggeration. If the purpose is to achieve an ideal integrator then a mathematica software is better suited. Otherwise, a value 1000x less that the period is often sufficient enough, without risking numerical issues with the solver due to the enormous dynamic range imposed to the timestep for the break points. Also, `numdgt` and `plotwinsize` are ony needed when greater than `float` numerical precision is required from the plots.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "brute force" example of "suppressing" drift in some applications.
It is used in some "opamp" amplifiers.
Used only on 50% duty cycle waveform, and perhaps (?) some others constraints ...

[image]